# XPEnology - Filesystem

Tags: filesystems, network-attached-storage, ntfs, synology

I've looked all over but I can't seem to find a straight answer.

I have 4 NTFS drives with data on them - are these compatible with a fresh install of XPEnology? 
The aim is to obviously share the drives and allow read/write.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are asking whether the data on the drives will remain there when added to a synology, then the answer is no. When you add a new disk, it will format it. Synology does not use NTFS, but instead [uses EXT4](https://www.synology.com/en-us/knowledgebase/faq/579). You could try consolidating and compressing the data onto one or two of the drives, add 2 and format, copy the data from the 2 NTFS drives, and then add those. You could do one at a time too, I believe you can start with just one drive.